# Fetching variables from an NPC handling/tracking class (C#/XNA)

Tags: c#, xna

I apologize as I don't really know how to describe my problem.

I'm working on a game which contains hundreds of levels, and will consequently contain hundreds of different NPCs. Since this is an MMO-style game where the states of all NPCs will need to be preserved, I've settled on creating a class that keeps track of each instance of every NPC for me, and when a player enters a level, it can provide the list for all of the NPCs in that area, where they go, etc. The problem is that since this NPC Control class stores a multitude of different classes, C# won't allow me to grab the information I need from them such as their x/y/image in my Draw method of my Game1 class since it doesn't know that those variables exist.

My current NPC control class looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyWorld
{
    public class NpcsControl
    {
        public List<object> GetNPCs(string levelname)
        {
            List<object> NPCs = new List<object>();
            switch (levelname)
            {
                case "garden2":
                    NPC_TreeBreakable NPCtree = new NPC_TreeBreakable();
                    NPCtree.x = 16;
                    NPCtree.y = 16;
                    NPCs.Add(NPCtree);
                    NPCtree = new NPC_TreeBreakable();
                    NPCtree.x = 16;
                    NPCtree.y = 512;
                    NPCs.Add(NPCtree);
                    NPC_TestLamp NPCtestlamp = new NPC_TestLamp();
                    NPCtestlamp.x = 16;
                    NPCtestlamp.y = 1024;
                    NPCs.Add(NPCtestlamp);
                    break;
            }
            return NPCs;
        }
    }
}
```

While my tree NPC code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyWorld
{
    public class NPC_TreeBreakable
    {
        public string image = "tree_new";
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }
}
```

I need to fetch this in my Game1.cs so that I can show the game where to draw these. Currently it is using this code:

```
foreach (object o in npcControl.GetNPCs(players[0].level))
            {
                object ob = o.GetType(); //ob == MyWorld.NPC_TreeBreakable
                imgpos.X = ((NPC_TreeBreakable)(o)).x;
                imgpos.Y = ((NPC_TreeBreakable)(o)).y;
                SpriteTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(((NPC_TreeBreakable)(o)).image);
                spriteBatch.Draw(SpriteTexture, imgpos, new Rectangle(0, 0, SpriteTexture.Width, SpriteTexture.Height), Color.White);
        }
```

The problem is that I'm being forced to manually input "((NPC_TreeBreakable)(o)).x" or "((NPC_TestLamp)(o)).x" instead of being able to just use ((ob)(o)).x since C# knows that not every class may have an "x", "y", or "image" variable. Even though they will be in each of the NPCs.

How do I fix this so that I can reference variables when C# doesn't know to expect them like this?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to learn and understand the SOLID principles of object oriented programming, my friend. You're violating the ISP (Interface segregation principle) and basically complicating your own code needlessly. I Recommend the book "Clean Code" by Robert Martin, but for a quick idea, just search for OOP and SOLID - you'll never go back once you understand those core principles of coding.